# Mqtt TLS certificate verify failed : self signed certificate

Tags: python, ssl, mqtt, paho

Am trying to implement TLS for mqtt and has followed the tutorials from the link below
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/

I followed exactly how it has been instructed to generate certificates using openssl and pasted in the location of mqtt and changed the conf of mqtt and restarted the service.
But when I try to connect to mqtt using tls it shows the below error message

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1124)
```

And python code is

```
client1 = paho.Client("control1")
client1.tls_set(ca_certs="ca.crt")
client1.tls_insecure_set(True)
client1.connect("localhost", 8883)
client1.loop_forever()
```

where ca.crt is in the project directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message you are receiving indicates that the broker's server certificate is not trusted (because it is self-signed), therefore paho is not being correctly told it is trustworthy.

It is possible your fake certificate authority's root certificate (the `ca.crt` file you feed to paho) is not properly signed or generated, or the certificates that Mosquitto is using are not signed correctly. Either way, you likely need to start the entire process over to be 100% certain everything was done right.

1. Generate the fake certificate authority's (CA) signing key
   `$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048`
2. Generate a certificate signing request for the fake CA
   `$ openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca-cert-request.csr -sha256`

   - Give the organization a name like "Fake Authority" and do not enter a common name (since your fake CA does not actually live on a server with a name)
3. Create the fake CA's root certificate
   `$ openssl x509 -req -in ca-cert-request.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca-root-cert.crt -days 365 -sha256`
4. Create the server / mqtt broker's keypair
   `$ openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048`
5. Create a certificate signing request using the server key to send to the fake CA for identity verification
   `$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server-cert-request.csr -sha256`

   - Give the organization a name like "Localhost MQTT Broker Inc." and the common name should be `localhost` or the exact domain you use to connect to the mqtt broker
6. Now acting as the fake CA, you receive the server's request for your signature. You have verified the server is who it says it is (an MQTT broker operating on localhost), so create a new certificate & sign it with all the power of your fake authority.
   `$ openssl x509 -req -in server-cert-request.csr -CA ca-root-cert.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 360`

Now you have everything you need. Make sure (as in Steve's tutorial) Mosquitto is loading the following in `mosquitto.conf`:

```
listener 8883
cafile certs\ca-root-cert.crt
keyfile certs\server.key
certfile certs\server.crt
```

Make sure paho-mqtt is loading the fake CA's root certificate.

```
client1.tls_set(ca_certs="ca-root-cert.crt")
```

This is how it knows that mosquitto's `server.crt` is legitimately signed by a "real and trusted authority" and is not "self-signed" and thus untrusted. Mosquitto and paho should now be able to securely connect and communicate.

Comment: Note that Mosquitto will need `allow_anonymous` set to `true` for this to work without setting up passwords or another user-authentication method.